# Update product price

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

basically i have two modules aos_products and fsubscriptions and what i want to do is update the product prices in fsubscription module when the prices in the aos_products module is change or updated.

here's what ive tried putting up together through some sample code using a logic hook to achieve this but it still doesn't work. What am i missing here ?

**UPDATED**

```
    class UpdateProductPrices
    {

        function do_UpdateProductPrices($bean, $events, $args)
        {
            global $db;

            $package_price = "SELECT price FROM aos_products WHERE deleted = 0 AND parent_type = 'FSUBSCRIPTIONS' AND parent_id = '{$this->bean->id}'";
            $GLOBALS['log']->fatal($package_price);

            $package_price = is_numeric($package_price) ? (float)$package_price : 0;

            if(!empty($package_price)){
                $bean->product_product_unit_price0 = $package_price->price;
                $bean->product_product_unit_price1 = $package_price->price;

            } else {
                $GLOBALS['log']->fatal('Product not found.');
            }
         }
      }
```

Ive change the price to $150 in aos_products:
[image]

but it doesn't change here in the fsubscription module it's still $100:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

first `$package_price` is a query definition that is never executed so no data will be there.

Second, you should really consider using suitecrm `pQuery` with the prepared statement array as arguments and not use it directly on the query (sql injection). Loos something like this `pQuery($query, ["arg1", "arg2"])` and the query will contain `?` symbols where you want the arguments to be replaced (order is respected).

If you want to fire on aos_products update then you need an after_save logic hook for the `aos_products` module as that's the one being edited.

Which means that `do_UpdateProductPrices($bean, $events, $args)` the $bean argument in this line will represent the PRODUCT not the `fsubscription`.

Third, you will need to verify is the price was updated `if($bean->fetched_row['price']!=$bean->price){` before updating.
Finally, lets try this code (please edit as I don't know the bean name)

```
        function do_UpdateProductPrices($bean, $events, $args)
        {
            global $db;
            if($bean->fetched_row['price']!=$bean->price){
            //means that the price has changed
                $fsubscriptionBean = new fsubscription();
                $fsubscriptionBean->retrieve($bean->parent_id);
                $fsubscriptionBean->product_product_unit_price0 = $bean->price;
                $fsubscriptionBean->product_product_unit_price1 = $bean->price;

         }
```